# Автопереход на другой контроллер

Tags: ios

Добрый день!

В моем проекте реализована регистрация и авторизация пользователей.

Задача такая: Если пользователь прошел авторизацию - перейти на другой контроллер. Если пользователь ранее логинился (данные кэшируются) - также перейти на другой контроллер.

Проблема заключается в переходе между контроллерами.

После успешной авторизации метод перехода успешно срабатывает, но при попытке использовать данный метод в условии, где осуществляется проверка логинился ли ранее пользователь или нет - возникает ошибка следующего характера:

*Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!*

Метод перехода к другому контроллеру выглядит следующим образом:

```
TabBarViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabbar"];
controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может заключаться проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот [тут есть решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883/whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy).

Если кратко, то вы пытаетесь вызвать навигацию с вьюхи, которая сама ещё не находится в визуальном дереве. Необходимо перенести вызов `presentViewController` во `viewDidAppear`, либо проверить, что он вызывается после `viewDidAppear`

Comment: Перенес метод в viewDidAppear и все заработало! Спасибо!

Comment: @AlexeySlivkin если ответ вам помог, отметьте его как правильный.